# Reportlab can't can't get bold or italic from newly registered font

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, reportlab

In my applications i need a font that can have romanian diacritics, so i found a times.ttf file that has them, my problem now is that i can't use italic, bold or boldItalic from it.

Here's my code:

```
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf', subfontIndex=0))
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new-Bold', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf', subfontIndex=1))
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new-Italic', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf', subfontIndex=2))
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new-BoldItalic', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf', subfontIndex=3))

registerFontFamily('Times_new', normal='Times_new', bold='Times_new-B', italic='Times_new-I',
                       boldItalic='Times_new-BI')


styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times", fontName='Times_new'))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times-indent-italic", fontName='Times_new-I'))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times-center", fontName='Times_new-BI'))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times-BoldItalic", fontName='Times_new-BI'))
```

For example:

If i write

```
p_text = "Hello"
report.append(Paragraph(p_text, styles["Times-indent-italic"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 5))
```

It will write it just like this: Hello, when i expect it like this: *Hello*. Basically whatever font option i want to use it will use the normal font. Any ideea what i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're referencing the correct filenames? On my system, all the variants are in their own TTF file:

```
$ locate times | grep ttf

/usr/local/share/fonts/webfonts/times.ttf
/usr/local/share/fonts/webfonts/timesbd.ttf
/usr/local/share/fonts/webfonts/timesbi.ttf
/usr/local/share/fonts/webfonts/timesi.ttf
```

I see that you only reference 'times.ttf'. Maybe your code should read:

```
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf', subfontIndex=0))
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new-Bold', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbd.ttf', subfontIndex=1))
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new-Italic', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesi.ttf', subfontIndex=2))
registerFont(TTFont('Times_new-BoldItalic', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbi.ttf', subfontIndex=3))
```

Comment: yea, you are right, i've seen a bad example using the same file on all variants, i am using courier-new that has a file for each variant now, so yes the answer is that you have to use a file for each variant.